# What "it" is referring in "it wasn't"?

Tags: meaning

Oskar, who is afraid traveling on vehicle, need to reach destination by walk but mute old man, Who is with him, replied by writing on piece of paper.

> Old Man: "I can't walk that far." if you wanted to go with me, it
>   would have to be on the bus or a train. And the train was a lot
>   faster. Anyway, there's nothing to be afraid of." To which you said.
>
> Oskar: It's easy for you to say!
>
> Oskar: Which actually... **it wasn't**. (Oskar Thinking this words)

Comment: It was not easy for the **mute** man to **say** something, because he is **mute**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here "it" is the thing that the old man wrote ("I can't walk ... nothing to be afraid of.").

Oskar said **it** was easy for you (the old man) to say.

Oskar thought that **It** wasn't (easy for the the old man to say).